# How to copy only certain counts for genes in tsv file to new file in linux

Tags: linux, filtering, awk, grep, featurecounts

Hi there I have generated a counts table of samples I need to compare by differential expression analysis.

The layout of the counts table is as follows:

| Gene_id | Sample_A_r1 | Sample_A_r2 | Sample_B_r1 | Sample_B_r2 | Sample_AB_r1 | Sample_AB_r2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KLTH001 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 5 | 8 | 3 |
| KLTH002 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 3 | 9 | 7 |
| YL99812 | 6 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 12 | 14 |
| YL99813 | 9 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 15 | 19 |

So here, for the differential expression analysis, I only want to compare for example the genes starting with "YL-". So in a new file I want the rows including the first row which is "Gene_id" and the sample names e.g. "Sample_A_r1" and then only the rows with genes starting with "YL-" in their names. This will allow me to only compare the changes between Sample_A alone versus when it was combined with Sample_B, or in the table Sample_AB.

If anyone can please give me an indication of how to do this in linux I would really appreciate it. I have seen other similar posts, involving `grep` and `awk` I am just not sure of exactly how to do this. I am still quite new to linux. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Would something like this work?

```awk ' $1 YL* ' counts_table.tsv > edited_counts_table.tsv```

Comment: Would this preserve the header/first line?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do job:

```
# creating a new file with the first line of the original    
head -1 foo.txt > bar.txt

# ">>" appends to the file on the right hand side
# "^" dictates that the search term should be at the beginning of a line
grep "^YL" foo.txt >> bar.txt
```

Comment: Thanks very much, will give it a try now

Answer (score 1):

One way using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'NR==1 || /^YL/ { print $0 }' file.tsv
```

The default action is to print the line/record, so all you need is the condition:

```
awk 'NR==1 || /^YL/' file.tsv
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out, it seems the previous command didn't copy all of the occurrences of "YL-" across. Could you maybe suggest how I could just remove any gene names starting with "KLTH-" from my original counts file as well? I would just like to be able to check that I got all records from the original file in the separated files I create.

Comment: @Justin1609 You can just negate the pattern match expression: `awk 'NR==1 || !/^KLTH/' file`. This will just print the first line, or lines that don't start with KLTH.

Comment: okay awesome thanks @Steve I appreciate it, will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `grep` like so to remove all lines starting with `KLTH`:

```
grep -v '^KLTH' in_file > out_file
```

For example:

```
echo "Gene_id\nKLTH001\nYL99812" | grep -v '^KLTH'
```

Prints:

```
Gene_id
YL99812
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses option:
`-v` : Print lines that do **not** match.

In the regular expression (regex):
`^` : Match the beginning of the line.